# Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes without name key including '[]'

Tags: php, post

What is the best solution to get the $_POST data from multiple checkboxes that have the same name attribute, **WITHOUT** using something like this;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some_value[]">
<input type="checkbox" name="some_value[]">
```

I'm using Unbounce to make a landing page, and they currently don't offer any way of setting the name attribute to something custom including the '[]' to denote to PHP to put the values in an array.

Comment: Why can't you just give them different names?

Comment: equal names means, that these checkboxes are "linked". That's especially true if you use radio instead of checkbox. Anyway I don't see anything why you should avoid such names.

Comment: Using Unbounce, I can't change their names to be unique either.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the POST data yourself using something like:

```
$formData = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

However, for parsing the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", you'll want to find a third-party library somewhere, as all of the native PHP options exhibit the same behaviour (later keys override earlier ones) that you would find with the normal $_POST structure.

Here's a "toy" implementation of a user-land version of [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse-str), with the added bonus that 'duplicate' values are turned into an array. I make no claims as to the quality of this code to handle all the possible edge-cases of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data:

```
<?php

$form = file_get_contents('php://input');

$arg_sep = ini_get('arg_separator.input');
$max     = ini_get('max_input_vars');
$token   = strtok($form, $arg_sep);
$data    = [];
while (false !== $token && $processed < $max) {
    if (false !== ($pos = strpos($token, '='))) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $token);
        $value = urldecode($value);
        if (strlen($key)) {
            if (isset($data[$key])) {
                if (is_array($data[$key])) {
                    array_push($data[$key], $value);
                } else {
                    $data[$key] = [$data[$key], $value];
                }
            } else {
                $data[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    $token = strtok($arg_sep);
    ++$processed;
}

var_dump($data);
```

For comparison, here are the guts of PHP's internal implementation - note that there is much more to it than this, but this is the heart of the key/value parsing logic:

```
    switch (arg) {
            case PARSE_GET:
            case PARSE_STRING:
                    separator = (char *) estrdup(PG(arg_separator).input);
                    break;
            case PARSE_COOKIE:
                    separator = ";\0";
                    break;
    }

    var = php_strtok_r(res, separator, &strtok_buf);

    while (var) {
            val = strchr(var, '=');

            if (arg == PARSE_COOKIE) {
                    /* Remove leading spaces from cookie names, needed for multi-cookie header where ; can be followed by a space */
                    while (isspace(*var)) {
                            var++;
                    }
                    if (var == val || *var == '\0') {
                            goto next_cookie;
                    }
            }

            if (++count > PG(max_input_vars)) {
                    php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Input variables exceeded " ZEND_LONG_FMT ". To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.", PG(max_input_vars));
                    break;
            }

            if (val) { /* have a value */
                    size_t val_len;
                    size_t new_val_len;

                    *val++ = '\0';
                    php_url_decode(var, strlen(var));
                    val_len = php_url_decode(val, strlen(val));
                    val = estrndup(val, val_len);
                    if (sapi_module.input_filter(arg, var, &val, val_len, &new_val_len TSRMLS_CC)) {
                            php_register_variable_safe(var, val, new_val_len, &array TSRMLS_CC);
                    }
                    efree(val);
            } else {
                    size_t val_len;
                    size_t new_val_len;

                    php_url_decode(var, strlen(var));
                    val_len = 0;
                    val = estrndup("", val_len);
                    if (sapi_module.input_filter(arg, var, &val, val_len, &new_val_len TSRMLS_CC)) {
                            php_register_variable_safe(var, val, new_val_len, &array TSRMLS_CC);
                    }
                    efree(val);
            }
next_cookie:
            var = php_strtok_r(NULL, separator, &strtok_buf);
    }
```